# Loading different stylesheet on Wordpress pages?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I have one stylesheet linked to my Wordpress page in header section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
```

Now, I want to load different stylesheets on a few pages or sub-pages.

What's the best/correct way of achieving this?

I'm thinking about writing my own shortcode calling "wp_enqueue_style", is that a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a shortcode for `wp_enqueue_style()`; it won't do any good, because by the time the shortcode is parsed, all the relevant hooks ( `wp_head`, `wp_print_styles`) will have already fired.

Write a function, in `functions.php`, to enqueue different style sheets based on `is_page( $id )` (where `$id` can be an ID, slug, or title). Then hook that function into `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

p.s. note also: you should be using `get_stylesheet_uri()` in your default stylesheet link, e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I you  want to just alternate any style href location or so, you can use this filter, example:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```